# looping through an object (tree) recursively

Tags: javascript, jquery, tree

Is there a way (in jQuery or JavaScript) to loop through each object and it's children and grandchildren and so on?

If so... can I also read their name?

**Example:**

```
foo :{
  bar:'',
  child:{
    grand:{
      greatgrand: {
        //and so on
      }
    }
  }
}
```

so the loop should do something like this...

```
loop start
   if(nameof == 'child'){
     //do something
   }
   if(nameof == 'bar'){
     //do something
   }
   if(nameof =='grand'){
     //do something
   }
loop end
```

Comment: object-keys and for-loop - differences details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54553880/860099)

Answer (score 122, accepted):

You're looking for the [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Statements/for...in) loop:

```
for (var key in foo)
{
    if (key == "child")
        // do something...
}
```

Be aware that `for...in` loops will iterate over any enumerable properties, including those that are added to the prototype of an object.  To avoid acting on these properties, you can use the `hasOwnProperty` method to check to see if the property belongs only to that object:

```
for (var key in foo)
{
    if (!foo.hasOwnProperty(key))
        continue;       // skip this property
    if (key == "child")
        // do something...
}
```

Performing the loop recursively can be as simple as writing a recursive function:

```
// This function handles arrays and objects
function eachRecursive(obj)
{
    for (var k in obj)
    {
        if (typeof obj[k] == "object" && obj[k] !== null)
            eachRecursive(obj[k]);
        else
            // do something... 
    }
}
```

Comment: @Val: it would be difficult to crash the browser with object recursion.  The object would need to contain a reference to itself as one of the properties :-)

Comment: try: `(a = {})._ = a`

Comment: @Annan: yes, that is more or less what I was getting at.  The point was simply not to do it ;-)

Comment: Are you guys saying this wouldn't work on an object with a DOM reference/circular reference?

Comment: I found I needed to ```// do something``` prior to calling eachRecursive() for Date objects otherwise this implementation skipped over them.  Dates are objects so eachRecursive() is called but in that case you don't really want to recurse.  That is what I found when using this.

Comment: object-keys and for-loop - differences details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54553880/860099)

Comment: For the `eachRecursive` you might want to not do the `else` comparison. Just go into `// do something` always,  and there `if (k === "child")`

Answer (score 22):

You can have an Object loop recursive function with a property execute function `propExec` built within it.

```
function loopThroughObjRecurs (obj, propExec) {
  for (var k in obj) {
    if (typeof obj[k] === 'object' && obj[k] !== null) {
      loopThroughObjRecurs(obj[k], propExec)
    } else if (obj.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
      propExec(k, obj[k])
    }
  }
}
```

**Test here:**

```js
// I use the foo object of the OP
var foo = {
  bar:'a',
  child:{
    b: 'b',
    grand:{
      greatgrand: {
        c:'c'
      }
    }
  }
}

function loopThroughObjRecurs (obj, propExec) {
  for (var k in obj) {
    if (typeof obj[k] === 'object' && obj[k] !== null) {
      loopThroughObjRecurs(obj[k], propExec)
    } else if (obj.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
      propExec(k, obj[k])
    }
  }
}

// then apply to each property the task you want, in this case just console
loopThroughObjRecurs(foo, function(k, prop) {
  console.log(k + ': ' + prop)
})
```

Comment: This works great for my own needs, thanks João. Would you know how I can access the keys also?

Comment: @KeithDonegan just pass also the key when you call the parse function, instead of `parse(obj[k])` use `parse(k, obj[k])`, and then later on use this function as argument instead `function(key, prop)`

Comment: @KeithDonegan I edited my answer according to your suggestion

Answer (score 6):

If you want to get back a tree of relationships you can use Object.keys recursively.

```js
function paths(item) {
  function iter(r, p) {
    var keys = Object.keys(r);
    if (keys.length) {
      return keys.forEach(x => iter(r[x], p.concat(x)));
    }
    result.push(p);
  }
  var result = [];
  iter(item, []);
  return result;
}

var data = {
  foo: {
    bar: '',
    child: {
      grand: {
        greatgrand: {}
      }
    }
  }
};

console.log(paths(data));
```

This can be extended to search for values within an object structure that match a function:

```js
function objectSearch(rootItem, matcher) {
  const visited = [];
  const paths = [];
  function iterate(item, path) {
    if (visited.includes(item)) {
      return;
    }
    visited.push(item);
    if (typeof item === "object" && item !== null) {
      var keys = Object.keys(item);
      if (keys.length) {
        return keys.forEach(key => iterate(item[key], path.concat(key)));
      }
    }
    if (matcher(item)) {
      paths.push(path);
    }
  }
  iterate(rootItem, []);
  return paths;
}
function searchForNaNs(rootItem) {
  return objectSearch(rootItem, (v) => Object.is(NaN, v));
}
var banana = {
  foo: {
    bar: "",
    child: {
      grand: {
        greatgrand: {},
        nanan: "NaN",
        nan: NaN,
      },
    },
  },
};
console.log("There's a NaN at", searchForNaNs(banana)[0].join("."), "in this object:", banana);
```

Comment: it doesn't console out the elements linearly, it seems they are in arrays as I run the snippet

Comment: object-keys and for-loop - differences details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54553880/860099)

Answer (score 3):

Consider using [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan). It's powerful for data processing once you wrap your head around it.

One great thing is that the items are traversed in "delete safe" order. So if you delete one, it won't mess up the loop. And you have access to lots of other properties like parents etc.

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');

const obj = { foo: { bar: '', child: { grand: { greatgrand: { /* and so on */ } } } } };

objectScan(['**'], {
  filterFn: ({ property }) => {
    console.log(property);
  }
})(obj);
// => greatgrand
// => grand
// => child
// => bar
// => foo
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@13.8.0"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)

Comment: Are there any typescript definitions for object-scan?

Comment: Unfortunately not yet. Really need to prioritize moving all my projects to typescript

Comment: I added some draft Typescript defs here https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan/issues/1674

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [sindresorhus](https://github.com/sindresorhus)'s [map-obj](https://www.npmjs.com/package/map-obj) & [filter-obj](https://www.npmjs.com/package/filter-obj) utilities ...

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31546658)