# How to filter an array of objects using all of each object's properties to check for a match?

Tags: javascript

Given a search string:

`Jane`

and this array of objects:

```
[
  {
    name: 'Jane Smith',
    address: '123 Main St, Boston, MA 01234',
    telephone: {
      primary: '1234567890',
      secondary: '1112223333'
    }
  },
  {
    name: 'John Smith',
    address: '333 Main St, New York, NY 56789',
    telephone: {
      primary: '2223334444',
      secondary: '3334445555'
    }
  },
  ...
]
```

we can filter the array by name:

```
arr.filter(person => person.name.includes(search))
```

Great. That works well if all we are only searching by each object's `name` property.

What is the best practice for filtering across all properties of an object?

Do we have to do something like:

```
arr.filter(person => 
  person.name.includes(search) ||
  person.address.includes(search) ||
  person.telephone.primary.includes(search) ||
  person.telephone.secondary.includes(search)
)
```

This becomes tedious and error prone if there are more than a couple properties.

Is there a way to filter an array if any property's value matches a search string?

**Update:**

This works nicely for top level properties on the person object.

```
.filter(person => {
  for (let property in person) {
    return String(person[property]).includes(search)
  }
})
```

Working on trying to find a nice solution for recursively searching through properties that may themselves be objects.

Comment: Would you want to do this recursively or for only the top level, you can iterate through properties of object literals using [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in).

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek, That works well for top level objects.  How would you then recursively test if `obj[prop]` is an object itself?

Comment: Same idea but you would call a recursive function, [take a look at this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2549320/looping-through-an-object-tree-recursively).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Object.keys` and `Array#some` in a recursive function (I have called it `deepIncludes`) to check if any property (or sub-property) includes the search string. Here I have used `this` to store the search string, because that allows you to `filter` your array of people with this syntax:

```
let result = array.filter(deepIncludes, 'Search String')
```

```js
function deepIncludes (object) {
  return Object.keys(object).some(k => {
    let v = object[k]
    return (v && typeof v == 'object') ? deepIncludes.call(this, v) : String(v).includes(this)
  })
}

let array = [
  {
    name: 'Jane Smith',
    address: '123 Main St, Boston, MA 01234',
    telephone: {
      primary: '1234567890',
      secondary: '1112223333'
    }
  },
  {
    name: 'John Smith',
    address: '333 Main St, New York, NY 56789',
    telephone: {
      primary: '2223334444',
      secondary: '3334445555'
    }
  }
]

// Usage:
console.log(
  array.filter(deepIncludes, '3334445555') //=> [ { name: 'John Smith', ... } ]
)
```

Comment: Excellent use of `.some`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `JSON.stringify` with the [`replacer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#The_replacer_parameter) parameter as a way to traverse the object.

```
function search(obj, str) {
  var found = false;

  JSON.stringify(obj, (key, value) => {
    if (!found && typeof value === 'string' && value.includes(str)) found = true;
    else return value;
  });

  return found;
}
```

Comment: Does this improve or diminish performance when compared to recursive `for...in`?

Comment: Without having done a benchmark, I would say that probably `for...in` is faster, since this code builds a JSON string (only to then throw it away), and will also continue doing a bit of work after the match is found.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I chose something close to this:

```
function search (obj, text) {
  for (let prop in obj) {
    if (String(obj[prop]).includes(text)) {
      return true
    } else if (typeof obj[prop] === 'object') {
      return search(obj[prop], text)
    }
  }
}
```

Usage:

`.filter(person => search(person, text))`

**Update:**

The `for...in` method does not work well for my use case. I'm not sure why, but some keys are not searched.

Using the `Object.keys` method works perfectly.

```
function search (obj, text) {
  return Object.keys(obj).some(k => 
    typeof obj[k] === 'object'
      ? search(obj[k], text)
      : String(obj[k]).includes(text)
  )
}
```

(same usage)

Comment: This code is a bit broken. For instance, it will return true when searching `search({a:{b: 42}}, 'b')`, since `b` (a property) occurs in the stringified object. Perhaps you should reverse the order of the two `if` statements.

Comment: @torazaburo, Yes, I'm noticing that now.  Will update if I figure it out.  Also, for some reason, some (top level) properties are not being searched at all.

Comment: @torazaburo, For some reason, using `Object.keys` works perfectly. But `for....in` does not.