# Loop to a filesystem structure in my object to get all the files

Tags: javascript, recursion

I get a Javascript Object from my server, which depicts a filesystem. Now I want to get the path of all files in the system, e.g. the endpoints of the tree.

File structure example:

```
└── pages
    └── services
        └── project            
            │── headline
            │── test
            │   └── text
            │   └── picture 
            │── text
```

Readable JSON:

```
{
"path":"/pages/services/project",
"is_dir":true,
"children":[
  {
     "path":"/pages/services/project/headline",
     "is_dir":false,
     "children":[

     ]
  },
  {
     "path":"/pages/services/project/text",
     "is_dir":false,
     "children":[

     ]
  },
  {
     "path":"/pages/services/project/test/",
     "is_dir":true,
     "children":[
        {
           "path":"/pages/services/project/test/text",
           "is_dir":false,
           "children":[

           ]
        },
        {
           "path":"/pages/services/project/test/picture",
           "is_dir":false,
           "children":[

           ]
        }
     ]
  }
```

]
     }

Expected output:

```
/pages/services/project/headline
/pages/services/project/text
/pages/services/project/test/text
/pages/services/project/test/picture
```

I played around a little bit with recursion and made a dumb function that works when a dir has only one child. My Problem is that I can`t grasp a way to handle more children. Is there a way to iterate over every child?

Here's my code:

```js
var json = {"path":"/pages/services/project", "is_dir":true, "children":[{"path":"/pages/services/project/headline","is_dir":false,"children":[]},{"path":"/pages/services/project/text","is_dir":false,"children":[]},
{"path":"/pages/services/project/test/","is_dir":true,"children":[{"path":"/pages/services/project/test/text","is_dir":false,"children":[]},
{"path":"/pages/services/project/test/picture","is_dir":false,"children":[]}]}]};

json.children.forEach(function (child) {
 out(goToDeepestPoint(child).path);
});



function goToDeepestPoint(node) {
    if (node.is_dir)
        return goToDeepestPoint(node.children[0]);
    else 
        return node;
}

function out()
{
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML += args.join(" ") + "\n";
}
```

```html
<pre id="output"></pre>
```

Comment: Your json isn't json. It's a Javascript object. For it to be json it would need to be a string. Json is a string notation. There is no such thing as a json "object"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [looping through an object (tree) recursively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2549320/looping-through-an-object-tree-recursively)

Comment: You can use a recursive function based on the length of children. Did you try that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was busy having a play with your original question and got this working:

```
goToDeepestPoint(json);

function goToDeepestPoint(node) {
    if (node.is_dir)
        node.children.forEach(function (child) {
    goToDeepestPoint(child);
});
    else 
        return out(node.path);
}
```

May not be appropriate in the light of your edit, but shame to waste it!

Answer (score 1):

working solution:

```
var json = {"path":"/pages/services/project", "is_dir":true, "children":[{"path":"/pages/services/project/headline","is_dir":false,"children":[]},{"path":"/pages/services/project/text","is_dir":false,"children":[]},
{"path":"/pages/services/project/test/","is_dir":true,"children":[{"path":"/pages/services/project/test/text","is_dir":false,"children":[]},
{"path":"/pages/services/project/test/picture","is_dir":false,"children":[]}]}]};

json.children.forEach(function (child) {
    goToDeepestPoint(child);
});



function goToDeepestPoint(node) {
    if (node.is_dir){
      for(var i=0;i<node.children.length;i++){
        goToDeepestPoint(node.children[i]);
      }
    }        
    else {
        out(node.path);
    }
}

function out()
{
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML += args.join(" ") + "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var json = {"path":"/pages/services/project", "is_dir":true, "children":[{"path":"/pages/services/project/headline","is_dir":false,"children":[]},{"path":"/pages/services/project/text","is_dir":false,"children":[]},
{"path":"/pages/services/project/test/","is_dir":true,"children":[{"path":"/pages/services/project/test/text","is_dir":false,"children":[]},
{"path":"/pages/services/project/test/picture","is_dir":false,"children":[]}]}]};

function getPaths(obj){
    let foundPaths = [];
    if(obj.children.length > 0){
        obj.children.forEach(function (element){
           let childPaths = getPaths(element);
           foundPaths = foundPaths.concat(childPaths);
        });
        return foundPaths;
   } else {
      foundPaths.push(obj.path);
      return foundPaths;
   }
}

let paths = getPaths(json);

document.getElementById('output').innerHTML += paths.join("\n");
```

```html
<pre id="output"></pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll share my answer because it's relevant to a thing I've been working on at the moment - it takes a more functional approach because that just happens to be what I've been studying

**Persistent iterators**

JavaScript's stateful iterators make me sad, so we can implement a persistent iterator interface using our own `Yield` and `Return` types. A `Memo` type is used but that is merely an optimisation detail.

```js
const Memo = (f, memo) => () =>
  memo === undefined
    ? (memo = f (), memo)
    : memo

const Yield = (value, next = Return) =>
  ({ done: false, value, next: Memo (next) })
  
const Return = value =>
  ({ done: true, value })
  
// example use
const ArrayIterator = (xs = []) =>
  xs.length === 0
    ? Return ()
    : Yield (xs [0], () => ArrayIterator (xs.slice (1)))
    
const it =
  ArrayIterator ([1,2,3])

console.log (it.value) // 1
console.log (it.value) // 1
console.log (it.next () .value) // 2
console.log (it.next () .value) // 2
```

Now, if necessary to create an *adapter* to interoperate with JavaScript's native generators, we can create a `Generator` type

Admittedly, this is not super interesting, but it does demonstrate the necessary functionality

```
const Generator = function* (it = Return ())
  {
    while (it.done === false)
      (yield it.value, it = it.next ())
    return it.value
  }

Array.from (Generator (ArrayIterator ([1,2,3])))
// => [1,2,3]
```

Our persistent iterators open the door for more exciting things like this tho

```
const MappedIterator = (f = x => x, it = Return ()) =>
  it.done
    ? Return ()
    : Yield (f (it.value), () => MappedIterator (f, it.next ()))

const ConcatIterator = (x = Return (), y = Return) =>
  x.done
    ? y ()
    : Yield (x.value, () => ConcatIterator (x.next (), y))

const it =
  MappedIterator (x => x * x, ArrayIterator ([1,2,3]))

Array.from (Generator (it))                      // => [ 1, 4, 9 ]
Array.from (Generator (ConcatIterator (it, it))) // => [ 1, 4, 9, 1, 4, 9 ]
```

---

**Pure expression**

Our persistent iterators give us a neat way to express a potentially complex traversal of our data structure. Here's one way we could write your tree iterator as a pure expression

```
const FlatMappedIterator = (f, it = Return ()) =>
  it.done
    ? Return ()
    : ConcatIterator (f (it.value), () => FlatMappedIterator (f, it.next ()))

const MyTreeIterator = node =>
  node === undefined
    ? Return ()
    : node.is_dir
      ? FlatMappedIterator (MyTreeIterator, ArrayIterator (node.children))
      : Yield (node.path)
```

Of course the answer is incomplete without a demonstration of working code

```js
const Memo = (f, memo) => () =>
  memo === undefined
    ? (memo = f (), memo)
    : memo

const Yield = (value, next = Return) =>
  ({ done: false, value, next: Memo (next) })
  
const Return = value =>
  ({ done: true, value })

// -------------------------------------------------------------------
const ArrayIterator = (xs = []) =>
  xs.length === 0
    ? Return ()
    : Yield (xs [0], () => ArrayIterator (xs.slice (1)))
    
const ConcatIterator = (x = Return (), y = Return) =>
  x.done
    ? y ()
    : Yield (x.value, () => ConcatIterator (x.next (), y))
    
const FlatMappedIterator = (f, it = Return ()) =>
  it.done
    ? Return ()
    : ConcatIterator (f (it.value), () => FlatMappedIterator (f, it.next ()))

const Generator = function* (it = Return ())
  {
    while (it.done === false)
      (yield it.value, it = it.next ())
    return it.value
  }
  
// -------------------------------------------------------------------
const MyTreeIterator = node =>
  node === undefined
    ? Return ()
    : node.is_dir
      ? FlatMappedIterator (MyTreeIterator, ArrayIterator (node.children))
      : Yield (node.path)

const data =
  {path:'/pages/services/project', is_dir:true, children:[
    {path:'/pages/services/project/headline',is_dir:false,children:[]},
    {path:'/pages/services/project/text',is_dir:false,children:[]},
    {path:'/pages/services/project/test/',is_dir:true,children:[
      {path:'/pages/services/project/test/text',is_dir:false,children:[]},
      {path:'/pages/services/project/test/picture',is_dir:false,children:[]}
    ]}
  ]}

// -------------------------------------------------------------------
// example use of generator around our custom persistent iterator
for (const path of Generator (MyTreeIterator (data)))
  {
    const elem = document.createElement ('p')
    elem.textContent = path
    document.body.appendChild (elem)
  }
```