# How To Loop Through A Nested Object

Tags: javascript, loops, object, properties, nested

Hi there i have an nested object that looks like this

```
var dogTypes = {
GermanShepard {color: "black and white"},
Beagle       {color: "brown and white"},
cheuwahwah  {color: "green and white"},
poodle:    {color: "purple and white"},
 }
```

im trying to loop through all the properties in a nested object i know how to do that with a regular object but not a nested one so if someone could help me that would be great.

```
 for (var key in dogTypes) {
 console.log(key + " : " + dogTypes[key])
 }
```

heres my code which prints out

```
 GreatDane : [object Object]
   GermanSheppard : [object Object]
   Beagle : [object Object]
   BullDog : [object Object]
```

where would i incorporate the color property in the for in loop please help!! thanks

Comment: `console.log(key + " : " + dogTypes[key].color)` ?

Comment: if its only two levels deep a double for loop would work, if not reursion or a while loop is a good idea

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2549320/looping-through-an-object-tree-recursively

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8085004/iterate-through-nested-javascript-objects

Answer (score 4):

> *"im trying to loop through all the properties in a nested object"*

A nested object is a regular object. You just need a nested loop if you want to reach all properties in the nested objects.

```js
var dogTypes = {
  GermanShepard: {
    color: "black and white"
  },
  Beagle: {
    color: "brown and white"
  },
  cheuwahwah: {
    color: "green and white"
  },
  poodle: {
    color: "purple and white"
  },
};

for (var key in dogTypes) {
  for (var key2 in dogTypes[key]) {
    console.log(key, key2, dogTypes[key][key2]);
  }
}
```

If there's only one, known key in the nested object, then you don't need a loop, but then you also don't really need a nested object.

Answer (score 0):

Its simple as:

```
console.log(key + " : " + dogTypes[key].color)
```

to access the color property.
If you add more levels have a look at: [looping through an object (tree) recursively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2549320/looping-through-an-object-tree-recursively)