# How do I make an object that has infinite depth through arbitrary properties in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm just curious, but how do I **make** an object that has *infinite depth* through *arbitrary properties*, in Javascript?
It would be an interesting stuff.

```
console.log(a); // is an object
for(let depth = 1; ; depth++)
{
    const arbitrary_property_name = Math.random().toString(36);
    console.log(a = a[arbitrary_property_name]); // is also an object
}
```

Comment: You can use recursive function

Comment: Possible duplicate of [looping through an object (tree) recursively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2549320/looping-through-an-object-tree-recursively)

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn This question is asking the way how to **create** the object, not how to _loop_ through it. Any creative ways to achieve it, else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be done with [*Proxy*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy).

```js
let the_void = {};
the_void = new Proxy(the_void, {get: _ => the_void});

console.log(the_void); // Proxy {}
console.log(the_void.this); // Proxy {}
console.log(the_void.this.is); // Proxy {}
console.log(the_void.this.is.interesting); // Proxy {}
console.log(the_void.this.is.interesting.isn.t); // Proxy {}
console.log(the_void.this.is.interesting.isn.t.it); // Proxy {}
console.log(the_void.this.is.interesting.isn.t.it['?']); // Proxy {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Example of recursive

```
var a = {};
var cur_level = 1;
function depth(obj,level = 0){
    if (cur_level == level) {
         return
    } else {
        obj.new_level = {};
        cur_level++;
        obj.val = Math.random(); //save some data
        return depth(obj.new_level,level); //make new level
    }
}
depth(a,100) // in this case if you using this declare u receive depth near 100 levels
//depth(a) -> in this case you will receive infinite depth of your obj
console.log(a)
```

Comment: `depth(a)` gives `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`, since it requires _infinite recursive_ function call.

Comment: it's infinite loop and it don't have end :) don't run it. I edited code to be easier.