# Infinite depth object that has _any possible property_ defined as a function that both is and returns another infinite depth object. JS

Tags: javascript, mocking, ecmascript-5

I want to create an infinite depth 'anything' object that has the following two properties:

1. Every property on the anything object is another anything object.
2. Every property on the anything object is also a function that returns an anything object.

The purpose is for simple mocking of objects in tests when a more specific mock is not needed.

Property 1 is fulfilled by [How do I make an object that has infinite depth through arbitrary properties in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45964798/how-do-i-make-an-object-that-has-infinite-depth-through-arbitrary-properties-in) but it is missing property 2. The solution must be in ES5 for runtime environment reasons.

```
var p = infiniteDepthObject();
// All of the following should be defined for arbitrary property names at any depth
p.foo
p.foo.bar
p.foo().bar
p.foo().bar()
p.foo.bar()
p.foo.bar.baz
p.foo.bar.baz()
p.foo.bar().baz
p.foo().bar.baz
p.someOtherPropertyChosenAtRunTime()
... etc
```

Can this be done in ES5 without a polyfill for Proxy?

EDIT:
Not a duplicate of [How does basic object/function chaining work in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099628/how-does-basic-object-function-chaining-work-in-javascript). I know I can return 'this' from a function to chain. The question is about defining all possible properties to be 'chain' methods. That is p.whateverYouCanImagine() returns p and also p.anyOldPropertyName as a property access returns p OR in both cases returns a new object that performs the same function as p. Not chaining, but some form of chaining *may* solve this problem. The difficult/different part is that at runtime I may choose a property to access that is not written into the object and it should still work.

Comment: Not a duplicate. I know I can return 'this' from a function to chain. The question is about defining all possible properties to be 'chain' methods. That is p.whateverYouCanImagine() returns p and also p.anyOldPropertyName as a property access returns p OR in both cases returns a new object that performs the same function as p.

Comment: @ponury-kostek I have edited the question. Please unmark as duplicate, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

This is a circular dependency:

```
const a = {};
a.a = a;
```

That's all, this is an infinite object, and you can replace the attribute a by a function to return same object

Comment: That is not quite what I was asking. Can I do a.foo() or a.foo.bar()? Yes a.a.a.a.a is defined infinitely but I'm looking for an object that is defined for all properties. Any property name at all.

Comment: ah, understand, no, Proxy covers the functionality you want, because is in the middle of any call so internally can perform the necessary checks, but, without a proxy, is not possible at all