# JavaScript looping through n dimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, multidimensional-array

I'm not so experienced in javascript, so I ask for a little help.

I have the following data array representation:

```
[name, obj1[name, type, obj2[name, type, obj3[name, type]]], obj4[name, type]]
```

Every object has properties as name and type.

The first name is the name of the main object. After that, if an object has another object inside, it opens new array for the properties of that object and potential other objects.

How can I iterate through this recursively and show this array in this way:

```
name(This can be left just as "name")
   name(of obj1)
   type(of obj1)
      name(of obj2)
      type(of obj2)
         name(of obj3)
         type(of obj3)
   name(of obj4)
   type(of obj4)
```

Comment: This is basically a tree traversal problem. I'd suggest you look up ways to traverse trees, and apply them here.

Comment: Add your attempted implementation

Comment: The structure of your data is not clear to me. Could you include a sample of the data as JSON?

Answer (score 1):

I hope, the last example in this answer will help you to solve your problem.
[Looping through the tree with recursive function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2549333/8131073)

```js
var data = ['name1', 
  ['name2', 'type2', 
    ['name2.1', 'type2.1', 
      ['name2.1.1', 'type2.1.1']
    ]
  ], 
  ['name3', 'type3']
];

function eachRecursive(obj) {
  for (var k in obj) {
    if (typeof obj[k] == "object" && obj[k] !== null) {
      eachRecursive(obj[k]);
    }
    else {
      console.log(obj[k]); // here you will see in console all items from your array
      }
    }
}

eachRecursive(data);
```

Comment: This should not be an answer but rather a comment. Give more context (an example) to beef this up or delete it.