# Why event properties are not easy to get?

Tags: javascript, object, events, properties

I have following code ( **[HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/5n2zagjc/2/)** is editable example - usage: type in input field and watch console):

```js
function test(event) 
{   
  let keys = Object.keys(event);
  let keysOwnProp = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(event);
  let keysForIn=[]; for(let k in event) { keysForIn.push(k); }


  console.log('keysForIn',keysForIn);
  console.log('keys',JSON.stringify(keys));
  console.log('keysOwnProp',JSON.stringify(keysOwnProp));
}
```

```html
<input oninput="test(event)" placeholder="type something">
```

**Questions**:

- Why only in `keysForIn` I see all(?) event fields/properties, but in `keys` and `keysOwnProp` only one: `isTrusted`?
- Is there an alternative for `keysForIn` (if yes, provide it) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here I copy-paste [Grégory NEUT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53542894/860099) answer - which looks like is the best one:**

`Object.keys(...)` returns the names of the non-symbol enumerable properties of the object, but only the ones which are not inherited.

`For...in` iterates the names of the non-symbol enumerable properties of the object, inherited or not.

`Object.getOwnPropertyNames(...)` returns all non-symbol properties *(enumerable or not)*.

---

To my knowledge there is no alternative to `for ... in` to get inherited properties

```js
function displayDetail(o) {
  let keys = Object.keys(o);

  console.log('Object.keys > ', keys);

  let keysOwnProp = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(o);

  console.log('getOwnPropertyNames > ', keysOwnProp);

  const keysForIn = [];

  for (let k in o) {
    keysForIn.push(k);
  }

  console.log('for ... in > ', keysForIn);
}


/**
 * The basic object
 */
const obj = {
  own: 'A',
};

/**
 * We add a non enumerable property to the object
 */
Object.defineProperty(obj, 'notEnumerable', {
  enumerable: false,
  value: 123,
});

/**
 * We create a new object based on the first (it will inherit it's properties)
 */
const objWithInheritedProperties = Object.create(obj);

console.log('REGULAR OBJECT\n');
displayDetail(obj);

console.log('\n-----------\n');

console.log('OBJECT WITH INHERITANCE\n');
displayDetail(objWithInheritedProperties);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems `Object.keys` & `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` gives the properties which belongs solely to the object where as `for..in` loop will also give the inherited properties

```js
document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('input', function(event) {
  let keys = Object.keys(event);
  let keysOwnProp = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(event);
  // location is one of the property which we get on using for..in
  console.log(event.hasOwnProperty('location'))
  let keysForIn = [];
  for (let k in event) {
    keysForIn.push(k);
  }
})
```

```html
<input id="test">
```

Comment: Can you provide some jsfiddle with proof? And, how to distinct that some field/property in object is inherited or not? So input event has only one non-inherited field/property (`isTrust`)?

Comment: ok so now we know that also `hasOwnProperty` not has access to properties that `for-in` has... but why (and is there an alternative) ?