# how to loop through an array of objects and access the properties inside each array to display in an html element?

Tags: javascript

I have a JSON response shown below :

```
rows: Array(2)
0:
ID: "35"
datedCreated: "2019-10-19 22:34:34"
text: "rferfrefrf"
userid: "1"
__proto__: Object
1:
ID: "36"
datedCreated: "2019-10-20 04:50:45"
text: "fesfsefsfdsdfsdfsdfdsfdsfsdfsdf sdfsdfsdfs"
userid: "2"
__proto__: Object
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
__proto__: Object
```

What I am trying to do is access the data within each object and have it displayed as a an html element like a div. In this case I would have 2 divs displayed on my html form. However if i returned 15 object I would like 15 divs each the different information of the objects. I know I am supposed to loop through the objects and I know I can do that using with the index but if I want the information divs to display automatically I think I would need to do a nested loop?  One that loops through the number of objects and then another one where I create the div element and supply it with the information from the object.. right? so far I have this.

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.rows.length; i++) {
for (var key in data.rows[i]) {
    for (var j = 0; j < data.rows[i][key].length; j++) {
        console.log(data.rows[i][key][j])
    }
}
```

}

And I get the first object

```
3
5
2
0
1
 9
 -
1
0
-
1
9
 ---- 
2
:
3
4
:
3
4
1
r
f
```

but I know I'm not doing it correctly. but essentially i would need this concept where it shows me the values for each object in the array. I know how to create the div i am just struggling with this

Comment: Unclear exactly what you want, but the innermost loop doesn't seem necessary. You could do e.g. `for (var i = 0; i < data.rows.length; i++) { for (var key in data.rows[i]) {  console.log(i, key, data.rows[i][key])    }}`

Answer (score 1):

you can use 'recursion' to achieve your goal. hopefully the link bellow can help you

[looping through an object (tree) recursively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2549320/looping-through-an-object-tree-recursively)

and try to run snippet, hopefully in can help you in some ways.

```js
var obj = {
  a1: '',
  a2: {
    b1: '',
    b2: {
      c1: '',
      c2: {
        d1: '',
      },
      c3: {
        d2: '',
      }
    },
    b3: '',
    b4: '',
    b5: '',
  },
  a3: ''
}

function eachRecursive(obj, text, dash) {
  temp = ''

  for (var k in obj) {
    temp += '<div>' + ('-'.repeat(dash)) + ' ' + k + '</div>';
    
    if (typeof obj[k] == "object" && obj[k] !== null) {
      dash1 = dash + 1;
      temp += eachRecursive(obj[k], text, dash1);
    }
  }

  return text + temp
}

document.write(eachRecursive(obj, '', 1));
```