# JavaScript recursive Object Map

Tags: javascript, recursion

**Im little bit stuck on mapping an object recursively, this is the source object :**

**source data :**

```
{
        "id": "41055788",
        "parent_id": "00000000",
        "organization": "Consejo Directivo",
        "level": 1,
        "children": [
          {
            "id": "51cd732c",
            "parent_id": "41055788",
            "organization": "Dirección General",
            "children": [          
              {
                "id": "28cd78ff",
                "parent_id": "51cd732c",
                "organization": "Direcciones Regionales",
                "children": []
                          ....
```

** I've been trying to figure out how to iterate through the tree and result expected:**

```
{
    "data":{
      "id": "41055788",
      "parent_id": "00000000",
      "organization": "Consejo Directivo",
      "level": 1
    },
    "children": [
      {
       "data": {
          "id": "51cd732c",
        "parent_id": "41055788",
        "organization": "Dirección General"
        },
        "children": [ ] ...
```

**this is what im on till now without success:**

```
**function tranformTransverse(root, tree) {
        let rmChd = Object.assign({}, root);
                delete rmChd['children'];
        this.dataTree.push({
            data : rmChd,
            children : (!!root && root.hasOwnProperty("children")) && root['children']
        });

        if ((!!root && root.hasOwnProperty("children")) && root['children'] instanceof Array)
            root['children'].forEach(child => {              
              this.tranformTransverse(child, tree);
            });

    }**
```

**Any Idea how to achieve this result?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [looping through an object (tree) recursively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2549320/looping-through-an-object-tree-recursively)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just recusively walk children, and uses destructuring to separate children out for processing, and place the rest of the properties in the data property as a new object.

```js
data={
  "id": "41055788",
  "parent_id": "00000000",
  "organization": "Consejo Directivo",
  "level": 1,
  "children": [{
    "id": "51cd732c",
    "parent_id": "41055788",
    "organization": "Dirección General",
    "children": [{
      "id": "28cd78ff",
      "parent_id": "51cd732c",
      "organization": "Direcciones Regionales",
      "children": []
    }]
  }]
}

const collector = ({children, ...data}) => ({data, children: children.map(collector)})
console.log(
collector(data)
)
```

Comment: nice answer! in this particular case, you can write `... => ({ data, children: children.map(collector) })`

Comment: this works like a charm, i was about shot me in the face, thanks god working in collaboration really hits in the nail.
thanks for the help... solution 100%