# Javascript read from all children in a json structure

Tags: javascript

I have a JSON structure like below:

```
"items": {
   "Part1": {
       "src": "xxxx"
   },
   "Part2": {
       "src": "yyyy"
   },
   //...
}
```

And I want to fetch all the src strings into an array regardless which part it belongs to. So I am trying to navigate through the different parts. How should I achieve this.

Comment: what effort have you made to solving the problem?

Comment: @DanielA.White Actually I am currently on a walkaround to this issue. And I am thinking of using findAllChildren but which seems to be applicable to an array instead of this structure. That's why I find this a little bit confusing

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2549320/looping-through-an-object-tree-recursively

Answer (score 1):

try this

```js
const items = {
  Part1: {
    src: "xxxx"
  },
  Part2: {
    src: "yyyy"
  }
};

const list = [];
for (const key in items) {
  list.push(items[key].src);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this

```js
const items =  {
   "Part1": {
       "src": "xxxx"
   },
   "Part2": {
       "src": "yyyy"
   }
}

const allSrcs = Object.values(items).map(i=> i.src)
console.log(allSrcs)
```

Answer (score 1):

For looping through json/object you can use `Object.keys` or `Object.values`. For example in your case,

```
let data = {
    "items": {
       "Part1": {
           "src": "xxxx"
       },
       "Part2": {
           "src": "yyyy"
       },
       //...
   }
};

let parts = Object.values(data['items']); // retrieve all parts in items
let srcs  = parts.map( p => p.src ); // src array for all parts

console.log(srcs);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this code:

```js
const jsonData = {
    "items": {
       "Part1": {
           "src": "xxxx"
       },
       "Part2": {
           "src": "yyyy"
       },
   }
};

const getAllSrcStringIntoArr = Object.entries(jsonData.items).map(([key,val]) => val.src)

console.log(getAllSrcStringIntoArr)
```

Answer (score 1):

To get all src into an array, you can use this solution:

```
const items =  {
   "Part1": {
       "src": "xxxx"
   },
   "Part2": {
       "src": "yyyy"
   }
};


const results = Object.keys(items).map(item => items[item].src);
console.log(results);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here it is:**

```
let vv = Object.values({
  "Part1": {"src": "xxxx"},
  "Part2": {"src": "yyyy"}
}).map(s => s.src);

console.log(vv);
```