# NestJS: Case-insensitive query parameters

Tags: typescript, express, nestjs

I'm migrating a .NET API to use the NestJS framework and I ran into an unfortunate problem. Case-sensitive query parameters!

This is migrate "in place" type work of a well used public API. Putting aside any philosophical feelings about whether params should be case-sensitive in the first place, I can't release breaking changes.

I found few articles on the Net. And [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69157949/nestjs-express-case-insensitive-body-fields) which deals with a similar issue. However, the suggested solutions are either laborious, or require altering all my DTO objects to have constructors.

I was thinking of something like this:

1. Middleware to convert all request params to a single case (upper, lower, whatever).
2. Custom decorator that takes a string. The string is the name of the freshly re-cased parameter.
3. That's it.

The calling code doesn't need to be rewritten. The controllers don't need to touched. The only substantive change required would be new decorators on interesting parameters.

Some example/pseudo code might better illustrate what I'm thinking. Here is Express middleware I used in a previous project:

```js
app.use(async (request, response, next): Promise<void> => {
    request.query = new Proxy(request.query, {
        get: (target, name) =>
            target[Object.keys(target).find(key => key.toLowerCase() === name.toLowerCase())]
    })

    return next();
});
```

And then the request DTO would look something like this (Hat tip to [Moshi](https://github.com/square/moshi#custom-field-names-with-json), the best JSON serialization library of all time):

```js
export class GetRequest {
    @NewDecoratorOfSomeKind('camelcasedname')
    @IsOptional()
    @IsString()
    camelCasedName?: string;

    // This would also work, which is neat. Useful?
    @NewDecoratorOfSomeKind('some_name_you_dont_like')
    @IsOptional()
    @IsString()
    aNameYouDoLike?: string;
}
```

So, before I spend most of a weekend figuring out whether this is even feasible, I seek the wisdom of the Stack Overflow. Cut holes into my plan. Is this even possible? Is it a pattern people would/should/could embrace? Is there something out there already that does this? Is there a better way to get the same result?